# Want summary page in rdlc showing sum of each page

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc

My requirement is that, I have list of customers and a want to build a report for salary structure. The report should show total on each page if number of pages are more than one and there should be a summary page at last which shows page wise total.

The first problem I have solved my restricting the records per page by 10 and taking the running sum at bottom. This shows total on each page. But I am not able to figure out the solution for second issue.

I want something like shown in attached image.
[Summary Page Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZjmY.jpg)

I was thinking of grouping the rows and taking total but its not working for me.

Comment: Hi Prashant.B, can you please update your question to include a text version of the table?

Comment: I have created the image in word and wanted to created same page vise total table in the last page of report(Summary Page).

Answer (score 0):

For total of all page's salary you can add a textbox in footer and add expression like this.
 =IIF( Globals.PageNumber =Globals.TotalPages,Sum(Fields!salary.Value, "DataSet1"),  "")

Comment: I want to show total of each page displayed on summary page as well. As shown in the attached image.

Comment: This link can help you  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2644f6a2-88e6-472b-ac99-96d15d885a47/total-at-the-end-of-each-page?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: I have already able to get the total at each end of page. Now I wanted is to show is each page total on last page of report as shown in attached image.

Comment: In above shared link did you follow these steps: **Right click the blank area in the Document window to the left of the report body, and then click Page Footer to show the Page footer.

2.       For grant total, please use this expression: ="Grand Total:" + Cstr(Sum(Fields!unit.Value)) in the textbox of the table footer

3.       For page total, drag and drop one text box control into the page footer section and fill in it using this expression: ="Page Total:" + Cstr(Sum(ReportItems!Unit.Value)) to caculate the total of each page.**